# both refer to the table from another scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

help help solve the problem.

I generated a scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold user
```

the result was:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 7)    
  end

  .....
  .....
  ..
  ...
end
```

then I generated:

```
rails g scaffold admin/user
```

the result was:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout 'adminpanel'

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  ....
  ....
  ....
end
```

views/admin/users/index.html.erb:

```
<pre>
  <%= debug @users %>
</pre>
```

as a result I get following error message:

```
NameError in Admin::UsersController#index
uninitialized constant Admin::UsersController::User
Request
Parameters:
None
```

Comment: Did you have `User` model in `app/models`?

Comment: Yes. Here I will not describe them

Comment: views/users/index it worked. but views/admin/users/index is not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the below in your `index` method

```
@users = User.all
```

to

```
@users = ::User.all
```